# Does the <aside> element belong to the main outline?

Tags: html

In MDN:

> The HTML Aside Section Element (<aside>) defines a section that, though related to the main element, doesn't belong to the main flow, like an explanation box or an advertisement. It has its own outline, but doesn't belong to the main one.

And here is my code:

```
<body>
    <h1>HTML5 Outliner</h1>
    <aside>
        <h1>MDN</h1>
        <section>
            <h1>Mozilla Foundation</h1>
        </section>
    </aside>
</body>
```

The output:
[image]

I find that the aside section belongs to the main outline. Could someone tells me where I was wrong?

The outliner which I used: https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/

Comment: As a side-note, please read this important observation by Steve Faulkner about the HTML5 Outline: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/10/html5-document-outline/ I understand that your multiple deployment of `h1` is well-intentioned (I was also doing this a few years ago) but you might be better off simply using: `<body><h1><aside><h2><section><h3>`.

Comment: @Rounin Thanks for your answer. But you may not understand what I ask.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "main outline". There is only one outline that encompasses the entire document, with sectioning elements (and sectioning roots) having their own headings and subsections. aside is a sectioning element, so any heading elements within the aside element will be created as subheadings, and any sectioning elements within it will be created as subsections.

I suspect MDN's "main flow" is just an informal term referring to the use of the main element to mark up the main content of a document. Unlike the aside element, the main element itself is in fact not a sectioning element.

Comment: In MDN: In HTML4, every section is part of the document outline. But documents are often not that linear. A document can have special sections containing information that is not part of, though it is related to, the main flow, like an advertisement block or an explanation box. HTML5 introduces the <aside> element allowing such sections to not be part of the main outline.